# Combine Column and Sort with condition using bash

Tags: linux, bash

How can I combine multiple column (and make reference column) and sort the data with condition (if not enough data, it will leave a space, comma or tab)

Here are the input:

```
Column A
00-03
00-06
00-14
00-25
00-54
00-59
01-08
01-42
01-49
01-59
02-08
02-10
02-17
02-18
02-23
02-48
02-51
02-54
02-57

Column B
00-04
00-44
00-51
01-11
01-25
01-43
02-00
02-03
02-24

Column C
00-19
00-46
01-21
01-26
01-38
01-47
01-49
01-52
01-58
02-16
02-20
02-57
02-58
```

I try using "**paste -d ','**" ,it can merged all the column but without leaving empty line if the data is not enough. If there any method or tools that merged the column and sort the column with conditions ?

Here are my desired output:

```
Heading,ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
00,00-03,00-04,00-19
00,00-06,00-44,00-46
00,00-14,00-51,
00,00-25,,
00,00-54,,
00,00-59,,
01,01-08,01-11,01-21
01,01-42,01-25,01-26
01,01-49,01-43,01-38
01,01-59,,01-47
01,,,01-49
01,,,01-52
01,,,01-58
02,02-08,02-00,02-16
02,02-10,02-03,02-20
02,02-17,02-24,02-57
02,02-18,,02-58
02,02-23,,
02,02-48,,
02,02-51,,
02,02-54,,
02,02-57,,
```

Comment: Since this is a very specific task, I don't think you can solve it with a simple standard tool alone. I would write a program which expresses explicitly what has to be done here. It **can** be done in bash, but it would be somewhat easier in a more general language (Ruby, Perl, Python). You basically need to manage 3 imput streams in parallel and one output stream.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a quick and dirty solution for your specific case.

This script needs 3 Files named a,b,c with your provided data.

```
mkdir temp 
echo Heading,ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
for i in 00 01 02 ; do 
    for j in a b c ; do 
        grep ^$i $j > temp/$i$j; 
    done
    seq 1  $(wc temp/$i* | head -n -1| sort -n | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'})| while read line; do
        echo $i >> temp/$i; 
    done
    paste -d',' temp/$i*;
done
rm -rf temp
```